# DBF Viewer 2000: Deleting multiple records from command line?

Tags: database, batch-file, dbf

I am trying to write a .bat file that will invoke DBF Viewer 2000 to delete all records out of a database with a date field earlier than 1/1/2006. However, I cannot seem to find anything anywhere that illustrates how to do something like this. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I don't know DBF Viewer 2000, but if you willing to use Python I could offer a solution.

Comment: If the DBF is one that has auto-increment columns, I know that a version of DBF Viewer doesn't respect it and actually hoses that column from auto-increment back to just integer data type... be careful

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about DBF Viewer 2000, but you can easily do this task using [DBF Commander Pro](http://dbf-software.com/). Use the following command in a batch mode (or in a .BAT file):

```
dbfcommander.exe -q "delete from 'D:\somefile.dbf' where date_field < ctod('01/01/2006')"
```

This will mark all the records satisfying the condition as deleted. To remove the records completely, use one more command:

```
dbfcommander.exe -q "pack 'D:\somefile.dbf'"
```

The program has 20-day *full-featured* trial period, so you can do the job within 3 weeks *for free*.